# How use wcf from wpf developed in .net core 3.0

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, .net-core-3.0

I need to use a WCF service from WPF developed in .NET Core 3.0 preview 5. In Visual Studio I cannot use Add -> Service reference because VS doesn't support this option now.

My first option is write in .csproj all components I need to running my project, but It doesn't work.

This is my .csproj.

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Connected Services\ServiceTime\Time.wsdl" />
    <None Include="Connected Services\ServiceTime\Time.xsd">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <None Include="Connected Services\ServiceTime\Time1.xsd">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadataStorage Include="Connected Services\ServiceTime\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Connected Services\ServiceTime\Time.disco" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Connected Services\ServiceTime\configuration91.svcinfo" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Connected Services\ServiceTime\configuration.svcinfo" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Connected Services\ServiceTime\Reference.svcmap">
      <Generator>WCF Proxy Generator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Reference.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="2.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="TimeService">
      <HintPath>..\..\TimeService\TimeService\bin\TimeService.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

TimeService is working correctly.

If anyone knows a guide about use WCF service in WPF use .NET Core 3.0 let me know please.

Comment: Wcf isn't implemented in net core. I never tried but it doesn't surprise me you can't consume wcf. You're supposed to use a restful service such as web api now.

Comment: @Andy - client side _is_ implemented.

Comment: And as for alternatives (server side), MS is hinting at gRPC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to use a WCF service from WPF developed in .NET Core 3.0 preview 5. In Visual Studio I cannot use Add -> Service reference because VS doesn't support this option now.

For .NET Core you add it as a Connected Service.

> ## [Use the WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide)
>
> ...
>
> The WCF Web Service Reference option is applicable to projects created using the following project templates:
>
> - Visual C# > .NET Core
> - Visual C# > .NET Standard
> - Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Core Web Application
>
> ...
>
> 1. In Solution Explorer, double-click the Connected Services node of the project
> 2. On the Connected Services page, click Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider. This brings up the Configure WCF Web Service Reference wizard:
>    [image]

Comment: Does that work for *any* WCF service? Any binding, any contract? Or just SOAP services with a WSDL?

Comment: @nvoigt It supports at least SOAP, websockets and net.tcp https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/tree/master/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/src/System/ServiceModel Also duplex where the binding supports it. No msmq. `dotnet-svcutil` isn't as mature as `svcutil` but for the most part you can wrangle it to do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot use Add -> Service reference because VS doesn't support this option now.

Yes it does. It's under "Add Connected Services".

It seems you want to add a WCF *client*, but do be clear about that. WCF services are not supported on Core.